# Leave only the choice of time in Datetime-picker in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, angular-ui-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I'm using AngularJS and I want to divide a datetime-picker in two parts. By default, where you open the calender, you have to choose the day and then the time (hours and minutes). I want to make two datetime-picker, one for the day and one for the hours/minutes. I tried to change this, in the first form:

```
 datetime-picker="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
```

into

```
 datetime-picker="HH:mm"
```

but it doesn't work.

The problem is that if you click on the first calendar to open the first datetime, it makes you choose the date before the time. Instead, I would like to choose only hours and minutes.

This is the plunker: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/BLPsNszpUWjXuHXaj7hO?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the datetimepicker component from this repo: https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker. It is mentioned in the documentation that you can use the following attributes:

```
enableDate - Whether you would like the user to be able to select a date. Defaults to true.
enableTime - Whether you would like the user to be able to select a time. Defaults to true.
```

So if you want to hide date picker part in the component, add `enable-date="false"` to your input field. Like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datetime-picker="HH:mm" enable-date="false" ng-model="ctrl.date.value" is-open="ctrl.date.showFlag"/>
```

Similarly, to hide the timepicker part in the component, add `enable-time="false"` to your input field. Like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datetime-picker="dd/MM/yyyy" enable-time="false" ng-model="ctrl.date.value" is-open="ctrl.date.showFlag"/>
```

Here is the update plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/luMPl8aOFkzBuW4BeNkx?p=preview. Hope this helps.